# Add category to my get_post query

Tags: wp-query

I am using this Query to pull in the latest 3 post

```
<?php
$query = 'posts_per_page=3';
$queryObject = new WP_Query($query);
// The Loop...
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
    $queryObject->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
            comments_template();
}
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I need to add from category 1

I tried adding

query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-3');

at the top of the query, it works but the formatting is not the same and the comment box is missing.

I am using this query in a tabbing plugin and is the only query that pulls in the comment box that works in a tabbing plugin that I have found, so I am trying to get this particular query to work

Thanks for any help

Comment: there is information in the WordPress Codex; for instance http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
$query = 'posts_per_page=3&cat=3';
```

?